# Indent textarea on keydown/click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have a label over top of my `textarea`.

When someone *clicks* or *keydown*'s on the textarea, I am trying to get the text to go to the edge of the label so it looks like that is actually where the textarea starts.

What I have right now is it finds the width of the label and then adds appropriate number of spaces to the beginning of the text area.

Firefox and Safari get's it very close to the label. But chrome adds a few extra spaces.

Could anyone help me figure out a more appropriate approach?

**http://jsfiddle.net/3jGv7/2/**

```
function cursorPosition(data) {
    var labelWidth = $(data).siblings('[class=indent]').width(),
        spaces = Math.round(labelWidth / 3.6) + 1,
        sVar = "";
    for (var x = 1; x <= spaces; x++) {
        sVar += " ";
    }
    if (!data.value.match(/^[ ]{'+spaces+'}/)) {
        data.value = sVar + data.value.replace(/^\s+/, "");
    }
    if (data.selectionStart < spaces) {
        data.selectionStart = spaces;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with CSS:

```
text-indent: 165px;
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/3jGv7/3/)

If you want a jQuery version:

```
var indentWidth = $('textarea.indent').prev('div.indent').width();
$('textarea.indent').css('text-indent', indentWidth+'px');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/3jGv7/4/)

Comment: Very awesome @jammykam! This is exactly what I was looking for. Youda man